# Xcode stalls on "loading" when trying to create new project

Tags: ios, xcode, project

Xcode 6 never gets past "Loading" when I try to create a new project. I actually was able to create a new project yesterday, but I decided to just ditch it completely (deleted). Clearly there must be a bad file somewhere, possibly related to the project I deleted, since I also see the same stalling behavior now with Xcode 5.1, which has worked fine for creating new projects in the past. Xcode 6 has worked fine when starting with an already existing project and still appears to do so. I did not see this exact problem in your data base, though one person saw the project creation freeze before reaching the stage I get to. Their solution was to delete Xcode and every possible file related to it, which I'm a little squeamish about, since I don't want to affect existing projects, and don't have an understanding of what the various files are for.

Comment: Try removing any left over reference to the deleted project. Then if that does not work, reinstall Xcode (you dont have to mess with its files, just use AppCleaner).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the DerivedData of Xcode should fix the issue. You can do this by heading to `~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData` (with a Finder window open press cmd+G) and deleting all the subfolders of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing, but if it could happen to me, maybe it could happen to someone else. The problem was that the window that came up after the second step in defining the type of project to be created, the one in which you choose where to save the project's files, extended off the bottom of the screen, so that only the very tops of the buttons were visible. Eventually, I realized the one to the far right might be the one to click to continue. Which it was. Feel free to delete this question.